# Dropdown menu bug in mobile needs two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a dropdown menu in mobile,
The menu only opens when i click twice. The first time it opens an closes very fast. The second click opens the dropdown menu ok,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data-cat-menu .mega-menu a.dropdown').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();

        if($(this).find('span.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-right')) { 
            $(this).find('span.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
            $(this).find('span.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        } else {
            $(this).find('span.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
            $(this).find('span.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        }
    });
});
```

.dropdown-menu already has a display: none, before the click.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

How can i make it open with only one click?

Edit:
I also tried the stop()

```
$(this).next('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideToggle();
```

Comment: Could your initial `.hide()` be disrupting this? try changing that to live in your CSS and do `display: none;`

Comment: already tried, i edited the question, no result.

Comment: Maybe try `.stopPropagation()` instead of `.preventDefault()`

Comment: not working either

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#data-cat-menu .mega-menu a.dropdown').on('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).find('span.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-right')) {
        $(this).find('span.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        $(this).find('span.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').show();
    } else {
        $(this).find('span.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        $(this).find('span.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
var dropDown = $(this);
if( dropDown.hasClass("expanded") ){
     dropDown.next('.dropdown-menu').slideUp("slow",function(){
         dropDown.removeClass("opened");
     });
}else{
     dropDown.next('.dropdown-menu').slideDown("slow",function(){
         dropDown.addClass("expanded");
     });
}
```